# AWS lambda trigger status

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I have few different lambdas with different kind of trigger. For lambda with stream (`arn:aws:kinesis`) trigger I am using `listEventSourceMappings` to find status. But I haven't found any API that I can use for other types like `arn:aws:events`, `arn:aws:logs`.

I am using `AWSJavaScriptSDK`.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure is this would be a suitable answer for you but there is an index of documentation on what types of AWS events can be used to trigger an AWS Lambda: [Supported Event Sources](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/invoking-lambda-function.html)